# How can I see which tables are used in a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have some views in SQL server manager, and I want to see which tables are being used to supply the data to the view. How do I do this?

Comment: `Right click > Script View as > Alter to > New Query Editor Window` Look at your tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the view in SQL Server Management Studio.

You can either click Design, which will give you a depiction of the tables, or Script View as ( Create/Alter) , which will open up the SQL used to produce the view.

First one is probably easiest.

Answer (score 2):

In SSMS right click on VIEW and select View Dependencies

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL Server Right Click on the view and choose Design...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
```

Answer (score 1):

This query should work:

```
SELECT view_name, Table_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
WHERE View_Name = 'view name'
ORDER BY view_name, table_name
```

The clicking around answers work fine, but I prefer to query things like this.